# how to insert dynamic data from sql into chartjs stacked bar chart javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, chart.js, stacked-chart

I'm trying to create a dynamic stacked bar chart with chartJS. I know how to create the a regular bar chart but have a problem when I try to create the a stacked bar chart.
For a stacked bar chart the data structure is different and I know how to constract it dynamically using javascript in the form

```
var inchartdatasets = [];
for (var i = 0; i < leninchart; i++) {
    var inlabel = 'label: ' + "'" + inchartlebals[i] + "'";
    var indata = 'data: ' + '[' + inchart[i] + ']';
    var indataset = '{' + inlabel + ',' + indata + ',backgroundColor: color,}'
    inchartdatasets.push(indataset)
}
```

The code above create the result in the following format (this is a copy from the alert) :

```
{label: 'AAA',data: [76.86],backgroundColor: color,},{label: 'Rating Unknown',data: [11.38],backgroundColor: color,},{label: 'BBB',data: [5.91],backgroundColor: color,},{label: '(1) others',data: [3.51],backgroundColor: color,}
```

To create the chart I use:

```
var data = {
    datasets :[
    {inchartdatasets}
    ],
};
var chart = new Chart ( ctx, {
    type : "horizontalBar",
    data : data,
    options : options,
});
```

this does not render the data on the chart even though the data in the alert is correct.
when I copy the alert message and hard code in in the data in the following code:

```
var data = {
        datasets :[
        {label: 'AAA',data: [76.86],backgroundColor: color,},{label: 'Rating Unknown',data: [11.38],backgroundColor: color,},{label: 'BBB',data: [5.91],backgroundColor: color,},{label: '(1) others',data: [3.51],backgroundColor: color,}
        ],
    };
```

the chart render correctly.

what am I missing here? why it does not render dynamically? any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that what you are constructing is a String, but the data you need to pass to chart.js should be a JavaScript object. See, by taking e.g. the string '{' and concatenating it with other values, what you get is another string, which chart.js can't work with.

Instead, what you need to do is construct your data as an object, something like this:

```js
var inchartdatasets = [];
for (var i = 0; i < leninchart; i++) {
    var data = {
        label: inchartlebals[i],
        data: inchart[i],
        backgroundColor: color
    };
    inchartdatasets.push(data);
}
```

[This MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) might also be a helpful resource to get a better understanding of working with JavaScript objects.

Comment: Thanks so much @Piet. For some reason this works partially. The values displaying in the chart are only the first digits. for example 76.86 will display as 7. any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Might be another issue with the data types you're passing or with the structure of your data. If you can update your question with a full example of your code (e.g. as a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)), I might be able to help.

Comment: I replicated the issue at https://jsfiddle.net/davidzohar/uqfgLzsw/25/ any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here's a [fixed version of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7euk1cvj/8/). The problem, and main change, was in line 99. The data for a dataset needs to always be in the form of an array, even if it only has one value. However, in your case, you were passing the value directly, which doesn't work with Chart.js.

Comment: you are the man! thank you so much for the great help with this.